# useOldManifestMerger causes build error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use this new feature available in the version 0.10.0 of the Gradle Plugin for Android. But I keep getting this error message:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':xxxxxx:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library
> >     com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0

Here's my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'
        useOldManifestMerger false

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard true
                proguardFile 'proguard-zap.cfg'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                debuggable false
                zipAlign true
            }
            debug {
                packageNameSuffix ".debug"
                debuggable true
                runProguard false
            }
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:+'
        androidTestCompile files('libs/espresso-1.1-bundled.jar')
    }
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Which version did you declare in your manifest for Android Minimum version ?

Comment: @gahfy I'm using build.gradle to set this

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.
As a temporary fix, you can add this in your manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    tools:replace="minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion"/>
```

The tools namespace is declared as follow: `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`. The downside of this fix is that you have to keep build.gradle and the manifest in sync with the value in `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. Hopefully it will be fixed in 0.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was fixed in 0.10.4